# How to pull an element from an array of arrays in Mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to find the format for a query to remove an element (with an _id) from an array of arrays in Mongo via Mongoose. I have read [the Mongo documentation on pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) and searched around, but cannot get the query format correct.

I know: the _id of the document in MySchema, the _id of the array element in outerArray, and the _id of the the array element in innerArray.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Mongo Schema:

```
MySchema {
    outerArray: [ {

        field1 : String,

        innerArray [ {

            field2: String

        } ]
    } ]
}
```

Mongoose Query - This does not work:

```
MySchema.findByIdAndUpdate( 
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId(docId),
        { 
            $pull: {
                'outerArray': {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(outerArrayDocId),
                        'innerArray': {
                            '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(innerArrayDocId)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        (err : mongoose.Error, updated : any) => {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query to solve your problem:

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate( 
    {_id: docId, 'outerArray._id': outerArrayDocId},
    { 
        $pull: {
            'outerArray.$.innerArray': {
                _id: innerArrayDocId
            }
        }
    },
    (err : mongoose.Error, updated : any) => {
});
```